# How do I get CustomerName from an Order?

Tags: php, magento

I had added a custom option `Complete` in action dropdown(sales->orders). It's working fine and order status changes to complete successfully.

I am integrating all orders with `Salesforce`. I have need of all of order details by `orderid`. Item details and grand total is fetched successfully.

Can anyone please help to fetch `Customer` name and his/her company name how submitted order. Below is my complete code to fetch order details:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$items = $order->getAllItems();
$_totalData = $order->getData();
$_grand = $_totalData['grand_total'];
$custname = $_totalData->getCustomerName();
$itemcount=count($items);
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
{
    $sObject2->Item_name__c = $item->getName();
    $sObject2->Unit_price__c = $item->getPrice();
    $sObject2->Sku__c = $item->getSku();
    $sObject2->Quantity__c = $item->getQtyToInvoice();
}
```

Answer (score 16):

try this

```
$order->getCustomerName()
```

Comment: Thanks Anton, its working for me. I need customerid and i am fetching them easily with your suggetion.

Comment: If it is a guest checkout order this will not return the name!

Comment: When order is  edited - 
can not get data - $order->getCustomerFirstname()
becouse not exist. 




better use $order->getBillingAddress()-> getFirstname();

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't need to cast `$order->getData()` to a new variable. This will only serve to chew up memory, especially since there is only one element you need from that data, which can be retrieved with a less intensive method.

Instead, try it this way:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$_grand = $order->getGrandTotal();
$custname = $order->getCustomerName();
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $itemId => $item)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

if `$order->getCustomerName()` doesn't work for you, try:

```
$order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
```

Comment: Hi Mike, is there a documentation to see all the methods that are usable?

Answer (score -1):

```
$custname = $Order->getCustomer()->getName();
```